# Create Objects Dynamically in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, object

Is there a (better) way to dynamically create Objects?

Right now I'm using a simple 'factory pattern' solution as following:

```
   String classType = generalObject.getClass().toString();

    if(classType.equals("class be.testApp.UserObject")) {
        return UserObject.fromByteArray(data);
//return new UserObject();
    }
    else if(classType.equals("class.be.testApp.NewsObject"))    {
        return NewsObject.fromByteArray(data);
//return new NewsObject();      
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use `toString` to get your class as a String... use `getPackage` and `getName` instead - or use the `class` attribute.

Comment: @Jean no need for `getPackage()`. `getName()` returns the fully qualified name

Comment: Try using `getClass().getName()` instead of `getClass().toString()`. At least you'll get rid of the unreadable `"class "` part of the string. Better: use `Class type = generalObject.getClass();` and `if (type.equals(UserObject.class))`.

Comment: this.getClassType() is also a posibility. Which is best and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is not a factory pattern and no object is created. You evaluate the class name and call a static method on a class.

---

Now it looks like you have an object (`generalObject`) and want to create a new instance of the very same type. *If* all possible types have a public default constructor (convention!), then you can use this to create a new instance based on the given object:

```
Object newObject = generalObject.getClass().newInstance();
```

(but maybe I still didn't get your idea...)

Comment: I'll try to briefly explain it. I've created a general DataObject class which is used by a few different Databases so I can generelise the use of it (e.g. addData(DataObject data)) in the database superclass. But I have several more explicit Classes (UserObject) that inherit basic db stuff from DataObject, but add specifik properties.

I could use the method you suggest, only there are no objects stored in the database, but bytes are (that's why I use the fromByteArray method).

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection here, something like

```
final Class<?> clazz = generalObject.getClass();
final Method method = clazz.getMethod("fromByteArray", data.getClass());
return method.invoke(null, data);
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
String classType = generalObject.getClass().toString();
if(classType.equals("class be.testApp.UserObject")) {
    return UserObject.fromByteArray(data);
}else if(classType.equals("class.be.testApp.NewsObject"))    {
    return NewsObject.fromByteArray(data);
}
```

This is very complicated. Since apparently both classes are on your compile classpath, just use the class objects, not their string representations:

```
Class<?> classType = generalObject.getClass();
if(UserObject.class.equals(classType)) {
    return UserObject.fromByteArray(data);
}else if(NewsObject.class.equals(classType)) {
    return NewsObject.fromByteArray(data);
}
```